# Find Latitude Longitude Using Address at the time of insertion

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I want to add Geo coding facility to the **address__c** field to **pba_listingobj__c** .The Below Idea I tried but it allows me to have LATLNG in **after insert and after update** .  I want to show error and don't allow to insert if LATLNG not found. For insertion **Its standard salesforce. Not ANY Visualforce**

```
trigger checklocationhavelatlong on pba_listingobj__c (before insert, before update) 
{
 if(trigger.isInsert)
 {
  String latlong='';
  for (pba_listingobj__c  t1 : trigger.new) 
   {   
     ClassGoogleGeoLocationCallout.getlocationlatlong(string.valueof(t1.address__c));
   }
 }
}
public with sharing class ClassGoogleGeoLocationCallout{
@future (callout=true)  
public static void getlocationlatlong(string address)
{
    // make post request

    string latlong='';
    string flag='no';
    double lat = null;
    double lon = null;
    HttpRequest objrequest = new HttpRequest();            
objrequest.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=false');
        objrequest.setMethod('GET');
        objrequest.setCompressed(false);            
        objrequest.setHeader('Encoding','iso-8859-1');
        objrequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        objrequest.setTimeout(120000);//max timeout
        HttpResponse objresponse = new http().send(objrequest);
        if(objresponse.getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(objresponse.getBody());
            JSONParser parser2 =JSON.createParser(objresponse.getBody());
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
            {
                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText() == 'status'))
                {
                     String txt = parser.getText();
                     if(txt=='OK')
                     {
                          flag='yes';               
                     }
                }
            }
            if(flag=='yes')
            {
                 while (parser2.nextToken() != null) 
                    {
                        if ((parser2.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser2.getText() == 'location'))
                        {
                           parser2.nextToken(); // object start
                           while (parser2.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT)
                           {
                               String txt = parser2.getText();
                               parser2.nextToken();
                               if (txt == 'lat')
                                   lat = parser2.getDoubleValue();
                               else if (txt == 'lng')
                                   lon = parser2.getDoubleValue();
                          } 
                        }
                    }
                latlong=((string.valueof(lat))+','+(string.valueof(lon)));

            }
            else
            {
              ApexPages.Message errorMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Error');
              ApexPages.addMessage(errorMsg);
            }               
        }
        else
        {
           ApexPages.Message errorMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Error');
           ApexPages.addMessage(errorMsg);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan on showing an error from a asynchronous method? Asynch methods run in the background in its own thread. The only way you are going to get this to do what you want is to make your method synchronous.

Comment: I am New to Visualforce and Apex. Its Just an idea !! Is it possible or not ?

Comment: I want to call google map API using post method. is it possible to call map api from trigger without post request ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand from the code that you are trying to save a record of `pba_listingobj__c` object, you want to perform a callout (which is not possible in a trigger).

Since you are doing a callout from a future you cannot prevent saving the record. What you can do is

- Either create a field and mark the record as invalid(creating a picklist with values as Valid/Invalid) in your future call and prevent any further action on that record unless the record is marked as valid i.e. by providing correct address. But since it is an async transaction, the user will have to refresh the page to check whether the latlong are found or not.

OR

- Create a VF page to over new/edit page and write you own save method which performs a callout synchronously and gives an error preventing save of the record. This will require more work as you will have to do it for classic view as well as Lightning.

Comment: Thanks Manjit your suggestions are useful ! I was avoiding to write New VF for saving because of 50 fields to be insert update delete